# PHP: How to check if user can access a certain group recursively?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a simple access check for my users. Basically I have an array of groups like `trial`, `paid`, `admin`, etc defined like this:

```
$levels = ['trial' => [], 'enterprise' => ['admin'], 'paid' => ['trial'], 
 'admin' => ['paid', 'editor'], 'editor' => []];
```

Take a look at the `paid` group. `paid` group has `trial` group in it's array meaning `paid` group users can access `trial` group too.

Similarly `admin` group can access `paid`, `editor` **and** `trial` group because `admin` has `paid` group in its array and `paid` group has `trial` group in its array (needs recursion I guess).

My function is like this (but I *can't figure out the recursion part*):

```
<?php
public function hasAccess($requiredLevel, $myLevel) {    
    global $levels;
    return (($myLevel == $requiredLevel) || (in_array($requiredLevel, $levels[$myLevel]));  
}
```

This works when the level is directly present in array but fails to make the associations, e.g. when levels are connected like `admin => paid => trial`

**How to modify this function so it can check this recursively in simplest way possible?**

P.S. The order in which they are stored is also not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
public function hasAccess($requiredLevel, $levels, $myLevel) {
    // Check if $myLevel matches $requiredLevel
    if ($requiredLevel === $myLevel) {
        return true;
    }

    // Iterate through all levels under $myLevel
    foreach ($levels[$myLevel] as $level) {
        // If any of those levels has access, return true
        if ($this->hasAccess($requiredLevel, $levels, $level)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I hope the comments clear it up enough for you.

I also advise you to pass `$levels` in as an argument instead of using a global variable as it allows for more flexibility, and globals are generally a bad practice.

The only thing you should watch out for are circular references, where you would end up with an endless loop. To solve this, simply pass the array of already visited levels as an optional argument:

```
public function hasAccess($requiredLevel, $levels, $myLevel, $visited = []) {
    // Check if $myLevel matches $requiredLevel
    if ($requiredLevel === $myLevel) {
        return true;
    }

    // Add the current level to the visited array
    $visited[] = $myLevel;

    // Iterate through all levels under $myLevel
    foreach ($levels[$myLevel] as $level) {
        // Return true if any of those levels has access,
        // and hasn't been visited before
        if (
            !in_array($level, $visited) &&
            $this->hasAccess($requiredLevel, $levels, $level, $visited)
        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: awesome! it looks so easy now but i just couldn't wrap my head around recursion before. thanks for the detailed comments in code. Also can you please explain the circular references bit? does that mean if the two levels refer to each other like 'admin' => ['paid'] and 'paid' => ['admin'] or is there any other case? Also how do I protect against it? Thanks so much.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by circular references. I updated my answer.